# How to run a background process before all foreground processes or a particular foreground process?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, ubuntu-14.04, cpu

> This is a program **system.c**

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    int main()
    {
        system("./client &");
        printf("WE are in main program\n");
        printf("WE are in main program\n");
        printf("WE are in main program\n");
        printf("WE are in main program\n");
        printf("WE are in main program\n");
        return 0;
     }
```

> This is **client.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("We are in background process\n");
    do {
        //doing some process on message queue to receive messages
    } while (1);
    return 0;
}
```

> How to get the output of
>   **./system** running from linux terminal as like as the below one

```
We are in background process
WE are in main program
WE are in main program
WE are in main program
WE are in main program
WE are in main program
```

> Can anyone please explain with much more clarity?

Comment: You want serialized runs using multiple processes? If you want the `client` to be executed first, why do you want to run it in background as a separate process?

Comment: The condition is 
1.I should run client in background 
2.system in foreground
and output should be like the above one

Comment: @pradeep do you have to use the system and client programs? Or is your task to create a process that runs a background process and wait in the foreground process until the background process is done?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a look at this and inspire yourself.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int pid;
    int status;

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1)
    {
        // handle error
    }

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        // exec child process
        execl("./client", "client", NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        wait(&status);
    }

    printf("WE are in main program\n");
    printf("WE are in main program\n");
    printf("WE are in main program\n");
    printf("WE are in main program\n");
    printf("WE are in main program\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ....It is a nice catch to use fork.But if client is doing some continuos running job.if it never ends.Then parent should always wait.I just want to know that my client successfully runs upto that print statement in client.Is there is any way to know such status...???

Comment: So your print statement may be understood as an initialization of child process. So parent should wait until child reaches some point (until it is initialized and running) and then kept on working without taking care about child anymore?